# how do I write a jQuery/javascript if statement so that it's triggered when a html <option> with a specific class is selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, selected

```
<select>
  <option value='34'>Trees</option>
  <option value='13' class='create_sub_category'>Add new sub-category</option>
  <option value='24' class='create_sub_category'>Add new sub-category</option>
  <option value='57'>Cats</option>
  <option value='34' class='create_sub_category'>Add new sub-category</option>
</select>



<script type='text/javascript'>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
if (selected(".create_sub_category")) {
  alert('hi');
}
</script>
```

Obviously, there's no such javascript or jQuery function called 'selected' that I used above in my if statement, but could someone help me find something that would do what I'm describing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('select').change(function() {
  if($('select option:selected').hasClass('create_sub_category')) 
  {
    alert("SELECTED");
  }  
});
```

You should put some id/class on that select element.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
if($("select option:selected").hasClass("create_sub_category")) {
  alert("hi");
}
```

The key here is: option:selected

Answer (score 0):

No need for jQuery

```
if(/\bcreate_sub_category\b/.test(select.options[ select.selectedIndex ].className))
    //...
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TZ5km/)

Comment: @mblase75: No, indexOf wouldn't return '-1' for `create_sub_category_extended`.